# how to scroll down a webpage

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm testing my new mobile website in Android devices.

But in emulator default Browser, I can't scroll down, right or left the page. There is no scrollbars, and arrow keys don't work, too. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8dhS.png) is a screenshot from my emulator window (I opened stackoverflow in browser)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I treat my mouse like a touch.
I left click the mouse button at the bottom of the emulator and drag the mouse to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you need to click the mouse left button at the edge of the screen for couple of seconds to activate the scroll. Once activated you use the mouse like a touch.

If you are not able to locate the scroll bar then go back and come back again on your page. While the page is loading, the scroll bar will be highlighted for a brief period of time. You can then click at the location as I have explained above in first paragraph.